# Vuejs props with a long path

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-props

I have a component with props like that:

```
 props: {
   data: Object
 },
```

data display: `{{ data.a.b.c.d.title }}`

I want to create a variable like: d = this.data.a.b.c.d.

data display: `{{ d.title }}`

What is the best practice to create this variable?

Comment: Are you really going to need everything in this object? Might be better to pass attributes in one at a time. Or create a more simple object that only contains what you need before passing it to the component.

Comment: because, I need a lot of data from props data. Forexample, c = this.data.a.b.c, d = this.data.a.b.c.d.,  or data.test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a computed prop, like this...

```
props: {
  data: Object
},
computed: {
  d() {
    return this.data.a.b.c.d;
  }
},

<!-- in the markup -->
<p>{{ d.title }}</p>
```

Comment: so putting code in the computed is the best practice, what is about putting it into 'watch'  like that:  `watch: {
    data() {
      this.d= this.data.a.b.c.d;
    },
  },`

Comment: You can use a watch *also* if you need some function to run when the data changes, but the computed prop is sufficient and correct for the requirement expressed in the OP.